# How to start companion app on mobile from smartwatch using RemoteIntent

Tags: android-studio, android-intent, wear-os

I have an android wear app, in which I want to have a continue on device button which launches the companion app on the mobile device.

When the App is already launched I can "restart" it using this Remote Intent.
How can I start the companion app from a standstill?

```
Intent intentAndroid = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                            .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
                            .setData(Uri.parse("myApplication"));
RemoteIntent.startRemoteActivity(context, intentAndroid, null);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured it out.
I missed adding an intent filter in the android manifest for the activity I wanted to start.
For example:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="myAppName" android:host="MainActivity" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then you can start it from the watch using:

```
Intent intentAndroid = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                            .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
                            .setData(Uri.parse("myAppName://MainActivity"));
RemoteIntent.startRemoteActivity(context, intentAndroid, null);
```